# get text of the clicked node treeview C# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

i have a difficulty selecting the text of a node in a treeview in c#,
the idea is get the text of the clicked node,
but the problem is that when i want to grab it like this

```
MessageBox.Show(treeView1.SelectedNode.Text);
```

the selected node is the previous selected, not the actual that i'm clicking, so how can i 
select first the node that i'm clicking and then grab his text after that? the solution i think is call the original nodeclick handler before i grab the text but i don't know how to call it

Comment: You shouldn't be calling any event handlers yourself. What event handler is your `MessageBox.Show` code in? Can you post the rest of the method surrounding that line for context?

Comment: i put that in the treeView1_NodeMouseClick handler

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it isn't selected yet when the NodeMouseClick event fires.  You ought to use the AfterSelect event instead.  That ensures it also works when the user uses the keyboard to select the node.  Or do it like this:

```
    private void treeView1_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e) {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Node.Text);
    }
```

But beware that the selection can be canceled by BeforeSelect.

Comment: it works, i didnt knew that "e" has all that properties, :). I don't understand what you mean with AfterSelect and BeforeSelect warning, can you tellme more about?

Comment: Check the MSDN Library articles for them first.  And do consider what happens when you use the arrow keys to select nodes.  The AfterSelect event is a reliable notification that a new node got selected, by any means.  You'd typically only use NodeMouseClick to display a right-click context menu that's customized for the node.

Answer (score 3):

You're correct in assuming that you're probably trying to access the `SelectedNode` property of the `TreeView` control before the node that was clicked actually gets set as selected. However, the answer here is not to call the event yourself (that causes all kinds of problems, and is generally a bad practice).

In fact, there's a much simpler solution. **The [`NodeMouseClick` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.nodemouseclick.aspx) passes in an instance of the [`TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenodemouseclickeventargs.aspx), which exposes a [`Node` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenodemouseclickeventargs.node.aspx) indicating the node that was just clicked.**

So you can change your code to simply access that property:

```
void treeView1_NodeMouseClick(Object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.Node.Text);
}
```

Comment: thank you, related to this i want grab the doble click event, but i can't, its appears that is impossible to have both working, can you help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void treeView1_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
 {
    treeView1.SelectedNode = e.Node;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I use `AfterSelect` event and a Button with a `Clicked` event to show the selected node text, and it works fine:

```
private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e) {
  Console.WriteLine(e.Node.Text);
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Console.WriteLine(treeView1.SelectedNode.Text);
}
```

Comment: to check the text of currently selected node

Comment: I still don't get it. That's what the `AfterSelect` event handler does. You're just showing that there are two ways to retrieve the currently selected node? I don't see how the button is anything but extraneous information.

Comment: I don't know where you put your checking code. You could add an instance variable (`string`, `nodeName` for instance), then put `nodeName = e.Node.Text;` in your `AfterSelect` handler method.